# How to use aurelia-validation to array item

Tags: validation, typescript, aurelia

please help me with `ensureForEach`, I cannot find documents of that point. I have a class:

```
export class EnterReplacements {
    replacements: Replacement[] = null;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private eventAggregator: EventAggregator,
        private repoCreator: RepoCreator,
        protected validation: Validation
    ) {
        this.validation = validation.on(this)
            .ensureForEach('replacements')
            .ensure('value')
            .isNotEmpty()
            .etc(); // repeat all the same stuff as in the Item validation
    }
}
```

It's get an error in runtime:

```
ERROR [app-router] Error: Error instantiating EnterReplacements. Check the inner error for details.
```

This's my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" repeat.for="replacement of replacements">
    <input  class="string-input" type="text" value.bind="replacement.value" placeholder.bind="replacement.friendlyName" change.delegate="$parent.onChanged()"/>
</div>
```

I need to validate all `value` property of items in `replacements` array is not empty. Please help !!!

Comment: Just our curiosity. Where to you get the .ensureForEach from? I can only find a reference in a ticket where a possible implementation is discussed. But for what I can see it's not there yet. https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/10

Comment: That's correct there is no ensureForEach

Comment: Do we have other ways to validate item in array?

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest release of [Aurelia-Validation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/2), the `Rules` for validating that an array is filled can be done through 2 ways:

The simplest way is with `minItems(count)`, for example we would use `minItems(1)` to make sure the array is filled with at least 1 item.

The second way which also works (we could use this for very specific validation rules)

```
satisfies(value => Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic function for validation and do it yourself (which would show on the top level as a validation for the array)

```
this.validation = validation.on(this)
        .ensure('replacements')
        .isNotEmpty()
        .passes(replacementsArray => {
           let valid = true;
           replacementsArray.forEach(v => {
             valid = v != null && valid;
           });
           return valid;
         });
```

Things to be wary of:
 - `isNotEmpty()` will run first (regardless of where it appears)
 - I believe isNotEmpty is necessary to get `.passes()` to run (that's been my experience, though I coudln't see a mention of that in the docs)
 - I don't actually know what you want to validate for each value, so I've done a null equivalence check, which I think would satisfy your `isNotEmpty` intentions?  You will probably want to change that.